# Which Polymer Table

Tags: polymer, web-component

I don't see an official Polymer Table component. A quick web search yields the following third party components.

It doesn't look like an official Polymer table is in the works. Am I wrong? Is there an idiomatic way of representing tabular data in Polymer, with Paper or Material design?

- [Data Table](https://github.com/knownasilya/data-table)
- [Csv Preview](https://github.com/dmaslov/csv-preview)
- [Aha Table](https://github.com/liuwenchao/aha-table)

Comment: Check out sortable table it's the best third party table I ever seen, and it's still in active development. http://files.stevenskelton.ca/sortable-table/examples/index.html

Comment: Playing around with it now. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Vaadin Grid https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-grid

It support huge data sets, sorting, filtering, cell customization and frozen columns. It has material design inspired styles so it will fit in well with paper elements. Apache 2 licensed.

Comment: the official Polymer paper-table component page proposes to use the Vaadin-grid is it's no more supported

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the table? If you just want a simple table to be displayed in a material-design style you can just use `<paper-item>` in a list or invisible table.

Comment: It's gonna be complicated to add options to such components, like sorting or resizing columns width.